# How to hide first hAxis label in AreaChart?

Tags: google-visualization

I use Google Charts to display area chart on my webpage. But due to its nature, first `hAxis` label is shown near first `vAxis` label (see an example in [the docs](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#SimpleExample) - 2013 there is near 0). If you change the type of chart to `LineChart`, then there is no such problem (see another Google docs [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Example)).

Is there any way to hide first hAxis label (and probably the last one)? I've tried to play with `slantedText` - still it doesn't look well. And `showTextEvery` doesn't help since the counting is always started from the first element.

See how my chart looks with `LineChart` type:
[image: linechart]

and with `AreaChart` type:
[image: areachart]

**Upd**. I can change `vAxis` to `continuous` type (`1, 2, 3, 4`). Then I can control what is shown and what is not with `ticks`. It can even help me to show proper labels:

```
hAxis: {format: '#', ticks: [{v:2, f:"17.03-23.03"},{v:3, f:"24.03-30.03"}]},
```

The only problem remains with tooltips - it still shows values like `1`, `2` etc. I've tried to play with [column roles](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles), but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see in those examples is the difference between continuous (`'number'`, `'date'`, `'datetime'`, and '`timeofday'` data types) and discrete (`'string'` type) axes, not a difference between the charts.

I presume, by the nature of your question, that you have a continuous axis type.  In that case, you can tell the chart which values to use for axis tick marks via the `hAxis.ticks` option:

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

`hAxis.ticks` takes an array of values or objects.  Values are points to place an tick mark at, objects have `v` and `f` properties, where `v` is the value to place the tick mark at and `f` is the label to use at that point, ex:

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: [{v: 1, f: 'label for tick mark at 1'}]
}
```

Comment: My hAxis is discrete and vAxis is continuous. Actually, I was changing just chart type and it was helping me to add extra spaces to the left and to the right, I've updated the question with images.

Comment: I've update my question based on your answer. Now the question is with tooltips - how to show proper (`f`) labels there.

Comment: When you add your data to the DataTable, use the same object format (`v` for value, `f` for formatted value) to enter the data for those data points and they will display properly in the tooltips.